# How to find the QR code for Facebook on Google authenticator?

Tags: android, facebook, google-authenticator

I was suddenly asked to enter a 6 digit pass code when trying to log in to the Facebook app from my Android (Samsung 20) today. Usually i find this code using my Facebook App, which I now have no access to. When I try the Google Authenticator the only account here my Instagram account, and that code is not working on Facebook. When trying to add a new account (my facebook account) I am asked for a QR code. I do have access to my Facebook account via my laptop, but I cannot find any QR-codes here. When trying facebook.com/security/2fac/settings - I am asked for the 6 digit code. Does anybody know how to find the QR-code on Facebook so I can add my Facebook-account to Google Authenticator?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, edited. Mye questiion is now both in the heading and at the end of the problem description